# Gather Rows with Matching Columns and Process into new Data?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of columns and I want to get the subset of data that exists where certain columns have the same value:

```
Col0 Col1 Col2 
A    beer 5
A    beer 439
A    wine 123
A    wine 1293
B    beer 493
B    beer 91
B    wine 944
```

So I need to select based on say Col0 and Col1. So it would go through and select everything where there is a match for Col0 and Col1.

So we have a result that looks like this kind of:

```
0: [A, beer, 5], [A, beer, 439]
1: [A, wine, 123], [A, wine, 1293]
2: [B, beer, 493], [B beer, 91]
3: [B, wine, 944]
```

Then I want to process the results into something else based on the other columns of data. So let's say check to see if the sum of Col2 is a prime, if it is create a new row in a different table with the value. If it isn't, find the closest prime and then add a new row with the closest prime instead.

Comment: Separate your second request `Then I want to process the results...` into a future post....one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Loading some libraries and your data `df`

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
df <- fread("Col0\tCol1\tCol2 
    A\tbeer\t5
    A\tbeer\t439
    A\twine\t123
    A\twine\t1293
    B\tbeer\t493
    B\tbeer\t91
    B\twine\t944",header=T,sep="\t") %>%
    as.data.frame()
```

I use `tidyverse` to reach your desired output

```
df1 <- df %>%
         group_by(Col0,Col1) %>%
         nest(Col2) %>%
         rowwise() %>%
         mutate(data = map(data,~paste0("[", Col0, ", ", Col1, ", ", .x, "]"))) %>%
         ungroup() %>%
         unnest(data) %>%
         group_by(Col0,Col1) %>%
         summarise(data = paste0(data, collapse=", "))
```

**Output**

```
   Col0  Col1                            data
1     A  beer    [A, beer, 5], [A, beer, 439]
2     A  wine [A, wine, 123], [A, wine, 1293]
3     B  beer   [B, beer, 493], [B, beer, 91]
4     B  wine                  [B, wine, 944]
```

If you want to save *only* your desired output

```
mylist <- df1$data
```